# Logic Interpretation of Fermat's theorem for n>1

Tags: logic

I am in a Discrete Mathematics course and the professor was giving examples of what a proposition is. I want to figure whether the following proposition is true or false.

Proposition: There are **no** positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^n +y^n=z^n$ **for some integer n>1**

My Question: I know that from Fermat's last theorem, $\not\exists $ any triple $x,y,z$ such that the equation holds for **n>2**. However, there are infinitely many triples satisfying $n=2$. So does the "for some" in the proposition mean for all n? If so, doesn't $n=2$ act as a counter example and deem the proposition false. and if not, then doesn't any $n>2$ deem this proposition true? I am just not sure what the **for some** really means here.

Comment: In common terms, a proposition is an expression where every variable is a boolean (true or false), and no variables are objects from the universe (integer, polygon, real number, group, etc).

Comment: So you mean that this is a predicate and not a proposition?

Comment: In first order logic terms, yes.

Comment: I see so in other words, This predicate is true when n=2 and false when n>2 correct? I think this is what was confusing me. Thank you

Comment: What a weird way of phrasing it, especially considering how well known the theorem is. I'd interpret it as false.  There are some integers (3,4,5. or 12,25 13 for example)  where it is true for some integer n > 1. (It's only true for n=2 but 2 is some integer.)

Comment: @fleablood but I can also say: there are no integers, x,y,z such that the equation holds for n=3 which is some integer >1 so it is true. I think that Like DanielIV said is that this is a predicate and not a proposition and its truth depends on the variable n.

Comment: oh, I see.  You are saying it is a question about n-- that for some n, there are no x,y,z.  Which is certainly true.  I think it's just as valid and much more natural to interpret this as a statement about x,y,z that there are none where it holds for some n.  Which is certainly false.  I think there is utterly no way to resolve this and I can not see any argument supporting yours is right over any other.  Mine puts the puts the quantifier into the statement early rather than later which far more natural and conventional IMO , but it is not absolute

Comment: See [Fermat's Last Th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Equivalent_statements_of_the_theorem) : it can be rewritten as : "With $n, x, y, z ∈ \mathbb N$ and $n > 2$ the equation $x^n + y^n = z^n$ has no solutions", i.e. $\lnot \exists n, x, y, z ∈ \mathbb N \ (n > 2 \land x^n + y^n = z^n)$.

Comment: But we know that for $n=2$ **there are** solutions; thus, we cannot say that "for all $n > 1$ ... has no solutions". So, we conclude with: "there are some value of $n > 1$ ... has no solutions" (where "some" alludes to all $n$ except $2$).

Comment: Did you understand my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here, as someone alluded to in the comments, is that it is unclear what is the order of your quantifiers.

1. > There are no positive integers $x,y,z$ such that there is some integer $n > 1$ for which $x^n+y^n=z^n$.

   False. Take $(x,y,z) = (3,4,5)$. Then indeed $n = 2$ is an integer more than $1$ for which $x^n+y^n=z^n$.
2. > There is some integer $n > 1$ for which there are no positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^n+y^n=z^n$.

   True. Take $n = 4$. Then there are no positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^n+y^n=z^n$, and this can be proven easily via elementary number theory. (No need for FLastT!)

The bottom line is that "$\neg \exists x \in S\ ( \exists y \in T\ ( \cdots ) )$" is not equivalent to "$\exists y \in T\ ( \neg \exists x \in S\ ( \cdots ) )$". The first one is equivalent to "$\forall x \in S\ ( \forall y \in T\ ( \neg ( \cdots ) ) )$"; while the second one is equivalent to "$\exists x \in S\ ( \forall y \in T\ ( \neg ( \cdots ) ) )$".

Relatedly, note that an assertion with two quantifiers in the order "$\forall \exists$" may be true but switching the quantifiers to the order "$\exists \forall$" may make it false.

Comment: I think that most mathematicians will bind later quantifiers to a smaller scope by default, so they would interpret your original phrasing to mean (1), which is false.

Comment: Some people put commas to weaken binding strength, but I recommend just making it clearer by putting all quantifiers on one side or using brackets or abbreviations.